# Laplace transform and tail probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-transform, tauberian-theory

Let $X \ge 0$ be a non-negative random variable. I would like to know if the following statements are equivalent:

1. $$ \lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[X e^{-\lambda X}\right]}{\log (1/\lambda)} = C.$$
2. $$ \mathbb{P}(X > t) = \frac{C}{t} + o(t^{-1}), \qquad t \to \infty.$$

(In the above, the constant $C>0$ is meant to be the same in both statements.)

I suppose this is connected to Tauberian theorems (which I am not familiar with unfortunately) but I am unable to find such form online.  It would be great if someone could explain how the equivalence could be proved and even better point me to some useful reference.

Comment: So in effect you are asking under what conditions $\lim_{t \to \infty} t P(X>t)=\lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} \frac{E[X e^{-\lambda X}]}{\log(1/\lambda)}$. But it seems to me that typically both sides of this equality are just zero, except when $E[X]$ doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Ian I hope it is clear from the context that I am considering the case where $\mathbb{E}[X]$ does not exist. After all this just follows immediately from the Laplace transform estimate (+ monotone convergence) in the first statement, or the tail condition in the second statement: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^{\infty} P(X > t) dt \ge \int_{t_0}^\infty \frac{C/2}{t} dt =  \infty$.

Comment: I guess the closest is the [*Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem#Integral_formulation), see the improved statement with the choice $L(t) = \log t$ and $\rho = 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the comment. I was actually aware of such Tauberian theorem when I was reading Feller the other day, but struggled to translate the result into my setting above. Maybe I should just try harder.